# server javaEE technology

Tags: android, jakarta-ee

I want to build a server that communicates with an android phone
based on a request/response model
At first i thought i will use Httpservlets and communicate with the android
by Http messages. but i need to be able to access a pretty big object with every
request so i guess i cant really transfer the object to the servlet.
so i know this is a pretty newbish question but iv'e been searching for days
what kind of java EE tech should i use(i thought of EJB but as i understand they cant communicate with android)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong questions. (I am not the one who gave you -1)

Comment: Ok that might be true (as i said in my question).so what is the right question?

Answer (score 1):

I think the right question is how to implement service layer for your android application:

Basically there are two options REST based web services and SOAP. Android's support for SOAP is inadequate and I personally prefer REST over soap any day. If you have decided to go with REST, your options in Java are Jersey, RESTlets  or Spring Rest services. I will prefer Jersey, but you can also look in to Spring ( although not strictly complaint with the JSR).

(note: look in "SO" for comparison on various rest based frameworks in Java)